# How to get value of variable in scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My ng-repeat="slide in slides" and my code looks something like this:

```
slides = [{ src: "/sikiosk/slidedata/Global/NA/USNS/Cafeteria/5000_24.jpg", interval: 5000 }, { src: "/sikiosk/slidedata/Global/NA/USNS/Cafeteria/5000_login-register2.png", interval: 15000}];
```

What is the best way to retrieve the intervals and store each interval as a variable? For example for slide 1, interval is 5000 and so on.

```
function nextSlide() {
            $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
            $timeout(nextSlide, interval);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the interval to the function in your html? Or if you have the index then just get it from slides `$scope.slides[$scope.currentIndex].interval`

Comment: how about `slides[$scope.currentIndex]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want the slide interval in the `interval` variable:

```
function nextSlide() {
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
    var interval = $scope.slides[$scope.currentIndex].interval;
    $timeout(nextSlide, interval);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to angular, and this helps a ton. Appreciate it. I will accept this answer once it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like slides is an array of objects, each of which has an interval property right?  you can  do:

`var interval = $scope.slides[$scope.currentIndex].interval`

Or if you'd rather an array of just intervals you could use something like lodash (note the use of the ES6 fat arrow -- you could replace that with a callback if you'd prefer):

`var intervals = _.select($scope.slides, (x) => x.interval)`

With callback

`var intervals = _.select($scope.slides, function(x){return x. interval})`